# How to fix some javascript basic grammar problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, modbus

I'm learning the NodeJS from few days ago.
I made modbus TCP communicator program in arduino. and I made a NodeJs server with mariaDB. 
I got some codes from many github sample sources. (ex. node-modbus, mariadb)
But when I mixed their codes, The problem began to arise.
Just I wanted to insert data in my database. 
I tried to make variables and I put code in setInterval function. but it failed.
I have two codes.

```
 client.on('connect', function () {
 setInterval( function () {
 client.readHoldingRegisters(0, 125).then((response) => 
 console.log(response.payload))
 asyncFunction();
 }, time_interval) /* reading coils every second */
 })"


 const mariadb = require('mariadb');
 const pool = mariadb.createPool({host: '127.0.0.1', port:3306, user: 
 'root', password:'###', database:'test',connectionLimit: 5});

 async function asyncFunction() {
 let conn;
 try {
 conn = await pool.getConnection();
 const rows = await conn.query("SELECT * from test.egtest");
 console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
 const res = await conn.query("INSERT INTO test.egtest value (?, ?)", [1, 
 "mariadb"]);
 console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }

 } catch (err) {
 throw err;
 } finally {
  if (conn) return conn.end();
  }
 }
```

---

```
var data_result;
client.on('connect', function () {
setInterval( function () {
 client.readHoldingRegisters(0, 125).then((response) => 
console.log(response.payload))
data_result= response.payload;
 asyncFunction();

 }, time_interval) /* reading coils every second */
})"
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({host: '127.0.0.1', port:3306, user: 'root', password:'###', database:'test',connectionLimit: 5});

async function asyncFunction() {
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await conn.query("SELECT * from test.egtest");
    console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
    const res = await conn.query("INSERT INTO test.egtest value (?, ?)", [1, data_result]);
    console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }

  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    if (conn) return conn.end();
  }
}
```

now NodeJS show error "response is not defined", I'm trying to put some codes of C or JAVA language. Maybe this is not same language.
How can I solve this? and How to learn basic grammar of javasciprt?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify what you mean by "grammar of javascript"? And also why are you using C and JAVA?

Comment: I suggest you start with a less challenging task, with basic node programming. Your error here is that the response obj is not being generated by read_client_registers, but honestly modebus is a lot harder than node, so go to the basics first. Cheer

Comment: my project is the IOT system. I just wanted that When I get some data from readHoldingRegisters. then next, insert the data to mariaDB database.

Comment: I was making some arduino app and android app and server app. so I confused grammar of language. maybe I need to take a break and study again. thank you for answer!